# Image not fitting in div, who can see for it

Tags: css

Hello everyone i am new with css. this is my website
https://cvowebdesigner.be/22652/Yasin%20Altintas/wordpress/index.php/over-de-club/

the image is not fitting and it repeats. How can i fix this with css?

thank you

Comment: what do you want to get? one image?

Comment: Can't see a repeating image on that site.

Comment: @A Haworth background under 'over the club' text

Comment: the first image is repeating and not fitting in div in the background

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `!important` to background properties, and it will work.

```
.page-title-section {
        background-position: top center !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        background-size: cover !important;
    /*rest of the code here*/
}
```

Edit:

Only on a higher resolution/screen size is the problem visible. You'd need to add a different `background-size` property...
or simply add: `background-attachment: fixed !important;`

Comment: No, [you don't always need `!important`](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) [2](https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/)

Comment: @vee true, but the case here is that it has to be added.

Comment: it is better it doen't repeat but now it is not fitting in the div.

Comment: https://cvowebdesigner.be/22652/Yasin%20Altintas/wordpress/index.php/over-de-club/

Comment: @iorgu Yes, you are right.

Comment: @YasinAltintas Mix with SandyKrish's answer, use `background-position: 100% 30% !important;`

Comment: I see that you are using WordPress and that header background is part of the theme. The theme itself already have background style with positioned+size+no-repeat. I have no idea that how your custom background image (bikers) was set. So, to make it best fit in the div maybe hard or you may control it via Customize menu if your theme supported it.

Answer (score 0):

Use these background CSS properties along with your background CSS property to avoid image repeats.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 100% 30%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `background-image` and `background-color` separate instead of together. If you dont separate them they will override your values of `background-repeat: no-repeat;` with `background-repeat-x: initial;` and `background-repeat-y: initial;`.

Inline:

```
<section class="page-title-section" style="background-image:url('https://cvowebdesigner.be/22652/Yasin%20Altintas/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/test-1.jpg'); background-color: #17212c;">
```

With CSS:

```
background-image: url('https://cvowebdesigner.be/22652/Yasin%20Altintas/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/test-1.jpg'); 
background-color: #17212c;
```

Comment: I dont understand can you please check my website and send the code:

Comment: https://cvowebdesigner.be/22652/Yasin%20Altintas/wordpress/index.php/over-de-club/

Comment: i am a beginner in css :D

Comment: @YasinAltintas Instead of putting color and background image into one `background` property, separate them into `background-color: #yourcolor;` and `background-image: yourimage;`. This will be allow CSS override easier without `!important`.

Comment: Can you send the css code for me please so i can copy it because it is to difficult for me

Comment: Updated my answer now! :)

Comment: thank you so i must copy inline code and css code to extra css in wordpress? :P

Comment: Dont know how your theme is done so I dont know, sorry. :/